# Graphql Sangria Many-to-Many example

Tags: scala, playframework, graphql, slick, sangria

I'm working on a Many-to-Many relation with Sangria and Slick.
I have 3 objects: Role, Permission and RolePermission (a mapping table)

```
case class Role(id: Long, name: String)
case class Permission(id: Long, name: String)
case class RolePermission(id: Long, roleId: Long, permissionId: Long)
```

So far I figured out how to define the relation:

```
val permissionsByRoleId = Relation[Permission, (RolePermission, Permission), Long]("permissionsByRoleId", tmp ⇒ Seq(tmp._1.roleId), _._2)
```

I don't know how to define the `fetcher` and how to add the right field to Role Schema, so that I could retrieve the Role's permissions passing by the intermediate table.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `Relation` type for both related entities. It's not easy to answer in short comment on StackOverflow, but I've explained such kind of relation in my blog post: https://scalac.io/akka-http-sangria-graphql-backend#implementing-many-to-many-relation I hope it helps..